# tracking user clicks within <iframe> (Wiki game)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am try to write a simple web based version of the wiki game, which starts with a url and has a goal url that the user must reach only by clicking links in the wikipedia pages.  The general idea was to have the starting wikipedia url in an iframe, and within the iframe the user can click links to go to other pages.

The problem is that it seems like there are restrictions on tracking user activity within an iframe unless the contents of the iframe are hosted from the same domain as the web application itself.  So if a user clicks on a link within the iframe which leads to another page, I cannot find a way to track the new page that the user has gone to.  Even if I could just get the name of the link they clicked on this would be enough. For instance, if the user clicked on a link within the iframe named Europe, I could use PHP to go to a new page and load the new wikipedia iframe dynamically.  It would look like the following:

```
<?php
    $article = $_GET["article"];
?>
<iframe id="frame" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<?php echo $article ?>"
```

There just doesn't seem to be an obvious way to track user activity within an iframe.  Any suggestions?  Also below is a link to a version of the game, which has the same general idea as what I am aiming for.  It also appears to use iframes to store the wikipedia pages.

http://cs.mcgill.ca/~rwest/wikispeedia/

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, if you can't add code to the iframe URL, you can't measure interactions with that page.

However, you could create a proxy that injects some code:

```
window.postMessage(window.location,'*');
```

You'll need to rewrite links on the page to refer to your proxy instead of their original targets.

Then on your host page:

```
window.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);

function onMessage(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

It's worth noting that this would effectively let arbitrary code run on a URL belonging to you. That probably presents a security risk.